# bitcoin smartcontract feature

Tags: protocol, bitcoin-core-development, smartcontracts

I am a noob, so please bear with me.

I'm wondering whether the Bitcoin Core team plans to integrate a smart contract feature evolving the Bitcoin scripting language in a more sophisticated one in the near for far future.

Afaik, the only work currently done is on sidechains. Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no such improvement planned for the protocol, only the expected BIP are listed in  https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/README.mediawiki.
but you should understand why in bitcoin only a limited scripting mechanism is used instead a VM with a contract language as for Ethereum (security reasons). the project [RSK](http://www.rsk.co/) aims to provide such opportunity through a sidechain, so explore it.

Answer (score 1):

Improvements are made to Bitcoin's scripting language via [Bitcoin Improvement Proposals](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/), or "BIPs." Not all BIPs are focused on script, but some are. New op codes are introduced and agreed upon by developers and miners. Recent examples of this are [BIP 65](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0065.mediawiki) and [BIP 68](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0068.mediawiki). One of the benefits of [BIP 144](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0144.mediawiki), or "Segregated Witness," is that its adoption should make scripting upgrades even easier.

It is important to note that a more sophisticated language alone may not solve all your smart contract problems. The other major hurdle is statefulness. Bitcoin natively supports two states: spent and unspent. Ethereum and Rootstock support a wider variety of states, which I believe Bitcoin would either have to hard fork or build via side chains.

Answer (score 1):

Smart contract functionality for Bitcoin is being planned via Rootstock:

https://coins.newbium.com/post/292-what-is-rootstock-cryptocurrency